# How can I send data by json in php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'am trying to use w3school example in my localhost but when I run it , it gives me this error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\json_demo_db.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\json_demo_db.php on line 7

I've just copied code from w3school and replace information about my db

here is my code

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);

$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "blog");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM ? LIMIT ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $obj->table, $obj->limit);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$outp = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

and it's my html and js

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>Get data as JSON from a PHP file on the server.</h2>

<p>The JSON received from the PHP file:</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp;
    obj = { "table":"users", "limit":10 };
    dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "json_demo_db.php?x=" + dbParam, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is the link of w3school's example ( PHP Database)

> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: Your prepare failed because you cannot bind table- and column names: `SELECT name FROM ? ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prepare()` method is returning `FALSE` because, you are not providing the table name to it.

And you are calling function `bind_param()` on `FALSE`.

Provide table name directly by:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM `$obj->table` LIMIT ?");
```

So, your modified code should be:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM `$obj->table` LIMIT ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $obj->limit);
```

Comment: I know it so why w3 use ? for both table name and limit??

Comment: Generally, we do not pass table names as parameters in prepared statements. Don't know about why w3schools use it :)

Comment: This code introduces a big sql injection problem that you definitely need to fix.

Comment: @Hassan, you are welcome. Best of luck for your learning. I request you to refer official sites like php.net, dev.mysql.com, etc.. for studying.

Comment: @jeroen, thanks for pointing it out. I will update the answer soon.